# How do I can protect android applications from decompile

Tags: android

I know my question is repetitious, but there is a website such as http://www.decompileandroid.com, and it can  decompile android applications. 
What is the best way to protect against this site.

Comment: As far as I understand by reading the few lines on the main page, that site **doesn't** really **decompile** an app. Since apk files are really **zip** files renamed, it only **extracts** all the files fromn an apk. But **it doesn't provide you the source code**. Bear in mind that the resources (such as the 9 patches and the xml files) will be still **compiled**.

Comment: Use **Proguard** to obscure your code. If you can afford, use [dexguard](https://www.guardsquare.com/dexguard). It won't keep your app totally safe from being decompiled, but it'll make the decompilation process a lot harder.

Answer (score 0):

**Progurard**

[Progurad](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) obfuscate your code so that it may became **hard** to decompile not impossible